# jest gives me a failed but it absolutely can't be

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, tdd

i am trying to run a simple test on purpose to be sure my jest setup works properly.

this is my test:

**users.test.js**

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import UsersList from './../../components/users/UsersList.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);
localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('UsersList.vue', () => {
  let store;
  const state = {
    User: {
      id: 1,
    },
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state,
    });
  });

  // TESTS
  it('has a created hook', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UsersList, {
      store,
      localVue,
    });
    expect(typeof wrapper.created).toBe('function');
  });
```

the Component i was testing is called **UsersList.vue** and i have definitely a created hook inside.
after running my test i get this message from my cmd:

```
 FAIL  vue/tests/users/users.test.js
  UsersList.vue
    × has a created hook (45 ms)

  ● UsersList.vue › has a created hook

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "function"
    Received: "undefined"

      39 |       localVue,
      40 |     });
    > 41 |     expect(typeof wrapper.created).toBe('function');
         |                                    ^
      42 |   });
      43 |
      44 |   // it('has timeFormatterMixin added to transform time output inside the list', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (vue/tests/users/users.test.js:41:36)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.799 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites.
```

does anyone know whats going on here?
i tried the test example from the very own documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)

Comment: The docs have `typeof MyComponent.created`, you have `typeof wrapper.created`?

Comment: u got me bro, thanks

Comment: Isn't it `MyComponent.options.created`?

Comment: Why do you want to check if there is a created hook? I would check the consequences of what is happening in the created hook once the component has been mounted.